# Error with appendChild: Node cannot be inserted at the specified point in the hierarchy

Tags: javascript, appendchild

There is an error with the function `appendChild` : <kbd>Node cannot be inserted at the specified point in the hierarchy</kbd>

JS :

```
var abc=document.createElement("div");
abc.style.position="absolute";
abc.style.width="10px";
abc.style.height="10px";
abc.style.left="10px";
abc.style.top="10px";
abc.style.backgroundColor="black";
abc.innerHTML="abc";
document.appendChild(abc);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/T7ZMX/

Can you please help me?

Comment: In case anyone else also has this issue, I was accidentally using `document.createAttribute()` when i meant to use `document.createElement()`

Answer (score 33, accepted):

You need to append to `document.body`, not just `document`.

To explain why `document.appendChild` doesn't work consider the following diagram :

[image: DOM Tree]

If that would be allowed that wouldn't be very useful since it will be a sibling of the `HTML` root element, that make it totally outside the content.

For more information : [Using the W3C DOM Level 1 Core](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document_object_model/Using_the_W3C_DOM_Level_1_Core)