# document.appendChild works fine on IE but it doesn't work on Chrome and FireFox

Tags: google-chrome, internet-explorer, firefox

**document.appendChild()** gives this error on Chrome "***Uncaught HierarchyRequestError: Failed to execute 'appendChild' on 'Node': Only one element on document allowed.***", doesn't work on Firefox either but works on IE. What could be the problem? Please help :(

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Error with appendChild: Node cannot be inserted at the specified point in the hierarchy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10744110/error-with-appendchild-node-cannot-be-inserted-at-the-specified-point-in-the-hi)

Answer (score 1):

You should use:

```
document.body.appendChild(obj);
```

You should append `obj` (in this case) to the `body`. Do not append it directly to `document`.